# SQL - Problem with a query to select with some condition

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have this two tables, in the first (WRITES) there are the books that are stored in the db (DOI indetifies the book code and ORCID the author of the book, in the second (QUOTES) there are the quotes on each book).
The result I am trying to achieve is to have the identification codes of the authors who in their books have mentioned books written by other authors and not by themselves

**WRITES**

```
Doi   Orcid
1     100
2     200
3     300
4     100
```

**QUOTES**

```
Doi DoiMentioned
1          4
2          3
3          4
```

***Expected output:***

```
ORCID Doi    DoiMentioed
200    2         3
300    3         4
```

My code:

```
(select w.orcid
from writes w
join quotes q
on q.doi = w.doi

minus

select w.orcid
from writes w
join quotes q
on q.doimentioned = w.doi);
```

I tried also with inner join but the result wasn't what I hoped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner joins should work, but you need to use the `WRITES` table twice: once for the mentioning author and once for the mentioned author.  Then compare them to make sure they're different.

```
SELECT w.orcid, w.doi, q.doimentioned
FROM    writes w
INNER JOIN quotes q on q.doi = w.doi
INNER JOIN writes w2 ON w2.doi = q.doiMentioned
WHERE w2.orcid != w.orcid;
```

Full example, with data from OP, to show it works:

```
WITH writes (doi, orcid) AS 
  ( SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 100 FROM DUAL ),
  quotes ( Doi, DoiMentioned ) AS 
  ( SELECT 1,4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,4 FROM DUAL )
SELECT w.orcid, w.doi, q.doimentioned
FROM    writes w
INNER JOIN quotes q on q.doi = w.doi
INNER JOIN writes w2 ON w2.doi = q.doiMentioned
WHERE w2.orcid != w.orcid;
```

> ```
> +-------+-----+--------------+
> | ORCID | DOI | DOIMENTIONED |
> +-------+-----+--------------+
> |   200 |   2 |            3 |
> |   300 |   3 |            4 |
> +-------+-----+--------------+
> ```

Comment: @Gwynbleidd I just updated the answer with data to show it works.

Comment: Thanks again!
After closing and reopening Sql Developer the query worked.